# Simple infinite scroll pagination using observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my app there are many tables that utilize server-side paging and searching. I want to make it so these tables use infinite scroll and I'm using a "Load more" button at the bottom of the table.  I want to create a single service that can be re-used in all of my views for all of these tables, but I am fairly new at rxjs and Observables and cannot seem to find the right way to accomplish everything I need.  Here is what I have so far:

An observable stream for searching that will return a new set of `QueryOptions` each time a unique search term is given.

```
// Setup our search stream that will trigger the $resources observable to be 
// refreshed upon search updating
this.searchStream = this.searchWatcher.pipe(
    // wait Xms after each keystroke before considering the term
    debounceTime(this.searchDebounceTime),

    // ignore new term if same as previous term
    distinctUntilChanged(),

    // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
    map((term: string) => {
        this.searchTerm = term;
        this.pageCurrent = 0;
        return new QueryOptions(this.pageSize, this.pageSize * this.pageCurrent, this.searchTerm);
    })
);
```

An observable stream for the paging that will also return a new set of `QueryOptions` each time we go to another page (since its infinite scroll, its always `this.pageCurrent++`). Obviously we will retain the `searchTerm` on all paged requests.

```
// Setup our page stream that will trigger the $resources observable to be
// refreshed upon the page being changed
this.pageStream = this.pageWatcher.pipe(
    map(page => {
        return new QueryOptions(this.pageSize, this.pageSize * page, this.searchTerm);
    })
);
```

Now I need to merge these 2 streams into a single `optionsStream` and tell it to start off with Page 1, and no search term like this:

```
// This becomes a stream of the most recently updated options
let optionsStream = merge(this.searchStream, this.pageStream).pipe(
    // this line initializes the page at page 1, with `null` as the search term
    startWith(new QueryOptions(this.pageSize, 0))
);
```

Lastly is my `dataStream` which just takes the options provided from upstream and makes a request to a backend server:

```
// This stream is the data stream triggered when the options are updated
this.dataStream = optionsStream.pipe(
    mergeMap(options => {
        // this.source(...) will return an observable of the items
        // I want to page through. e.g. returns a `Obserable<any[]>`
        return this.source(options);
    })
);
```

So far this all has worked great and I get the proper updates when any of these 2 streams make changes to the options.  Now my problem has been trying to figure out how to do 2 things:

1. I need to accumulate all of the events that come from my `dataStream` so that if page 1 has 10 items, then upon going to page 2, there should now be 20 items, then page 3 there would be 30 items, and so on.  I think I can use `scan` to do this and have even written a little test scenario that accumulates "pages" like this:

```
let page1 = [1, 2, 3];
let page2 = [4, 5, 6];
let page3 = [7, 8, 9];

let pager = new BehaviorSubject([]);
let pagerObs = pager.asObservable();

pagerObs.pipe(
    scan((acc, val) => {
        return acc.concat(val);
    })
).subscribe(page => {
    console.log(page);
});

setTimeout(() => {
    pager.next(page1);
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
    pager.next(page2);
}, 4000);

setTimeout(() => {
    pager.next(page3);
}, 6000);

// output looks like [1,2,3], then [1,2,3,4,5,6], then [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
// which is exactly what I want!
```

2. When a new search term is used, I need to "reset" the observable so that the `scan` starts over with an empty set `[]`, however I cannot figure out the right way to accomplish this using pure observables.

Can someone fill in the blanks here on how I might achieve this kind of functionality using observables?

TL;DR

When using `scan` operator in rxjs to page through a backend server with lots of objects, what is the best way to "reset" the  accumulator and start from scratch given someone updates the search term and therefore the paging has to start back at Page 1.

**UPDATE**

Ok I think I figured it out, but I have a feeling that this is a little hacky and isn't utilizing the observable operators as they were intended:

If I take my data stream and use `scan`, I can augment the pipeline to simply return just `val` in the case that the page was reset back to `0`. This appears to work at first glance, but I will have to continue testing it out.

Will leave the question open for anyone that has a more elegant solution or suggestions

```
this.$resources = this.dataStream.pipe(
    scan((acc, val) => {
        return this.pageCurrent == 0 ? val : acc.concat(val);
    }),
    share(),
    tap(_ => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.isSearching = false;
    })
);
```

Comment: Did you manage to implement this some other way? I also went for this solution coincidentally, and was searching for another way to do it

Comment: @LogixMaster sorry I did not actually. I even found other that ended up using this to get the same functionality so I took that as justification for doing so. However, seeing how it was a bit complicated I ended up writing an abstraction in a core library for my organization in order to get this functionality easier for some arbitrary pagable API.